# Old anime where a girl comes from a star

Tags: story-identification, anime

What’s the name of the anime that’s about a girl coming from a star?  The main character is two boys that’s friends and when the girl come from a star one of the boys transform into a monster. Later on another girl appear which is her sister and she falls for the normal boy. Throughout the show the boy that turn into a monster past keep popping up. Also the first sister ended up destroying the world.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! I'm certain you can come up with some more details for us. These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 7):

I know you said "older" but 15 years counts, right? This sounds a lot like [This Ugly Yet Beautiful World](https://myanimelist.net/anime/146/Kono_Minikuku_mo_Utsukushii_Sekai), namely:

> two boys that's friends

Takeru and Ryou

> when the girl come from a star

The on-the-nose-named Hoshino Hikari, who falls mysteriously from the sky as Takeru is riding on his motorcycle

> one of the boys transform into a monster

Takeru turns into a black and red monster as seen here:
[image: black and red monster]

> Later on another girl appear which is her sister

Akari is a good fit for this, she appears in the same "falling from the heavens" type manner and considers Hikari to be her "older sister."

> Throughout the show the boy that turn into a monster past keep popping up

This I can't precisely match to the series, but I wouldn't doubt it.

> Also the first sister ended up destroying the world

Near-match, as Hikari decides to end the world, but is stopped by Takeru's love for her.

How I found it: I watched this myself in the late-2000s, and reading your question made me think of it.